# Lazarus BitsPerPixel error

Tags: linux, lazarus

There is a simple application written in Lazarus. When it tries to open graphical file it gets and "incompatible BitsPerPixel" error. OS: Debian. Lazarus: 1.4.0. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
ERROR in LCL: TGtk2WidgetSet.CreateBitmapFromRawImage Incompatible BitsPerPixel

Creating gdb catchable error:
$000000000050B225 line 720 of lazloggerbase.pas
$00000000004BCBDE line 1414 of lclproc.pas
$00000000004BAB0B line 859 of lclproc.pas
$00000000005E38A6 line 417 of gtk2lclintf.inc
$0000000000568A45 line 152 of include/lclintf.inc
$00000000004DB208 line 3622 of intfgraphics.pas
$000000000054A7BA line 554 of include/rasterimage.inc
$000000000045FDC3 line 86 of unit1.pas
$0000000000460258 line 144 of unit1.pas
TApplication.HandleException Failed to create handles
Stack trace:
$00000000004DB22E line 3623 of intfgraphics.pas
$000000000054A7BA line 554 of include/rasterimage.inc
$000000000045FDC3 line 86 of unit1.pas
$0000000000460258 line 144 of unit1.pas
$00000000006346A8 line 2724 of include/control.inc
$00000000006636E6 line 54 of include/buttoncontrol.inc
$0000000000663FD6 line 169 of include/buttons.inc
$00000000006635E9 line 20 of include/buttoncontrol.inc
$000000000042E411
$00000000006241C1 line 5341 of include/wincontrol.inc
$000000000070B585 line 112 of lclmessageglue.pas
$000000000071ADB2 line 2423 of gtk2wsstdctrls.pp
```

code:

```
        procedure TForm1.ReadFromImage(var img: TRGBArray);
        var px,py: integer;  
            row: pRGBTripleArray;
            lazImage : TLazIntfImage;
            rawImage: TRawImage;
        begin
           If OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
          begin
            rawImage.Init;                                   
            rawImage.Description.Init_BPP24_B8G8R8_BIO_TTB(0,0);
            rawImage.CreateData(false);                         

            lazImage:=TLazIntfImage.Create(0,0);    
            lazImage.SetRawImage(rawImage);        
            lazImage.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
            SetLength(img,lazImage.Width,lazImage.Height);     

            Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromIntfImage(lazImage); 
            lazImage.Free;
          end;
        end;
```

xwininfo results:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x1a0002d "RGB<->XYZ<->Lab"
Absolute upper-left X:  642
Absolute upper-left Y:  37
Relative upper-left X:  2
Relative upper-left Y:  0
Width: 636
Height: 1041
Depth: 24
Visual: 0x20
Visual Class: TrueColor
Border width: 0
Class: InputOutput
Colormap: 0x22 (installed)
Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
Backing Store State: NotUseful
Save Under State: no
Map State: IsViewable
Override Redirect State: no
Corners:  +642+37  -642+37  -642-2  +642-2 
-geometry 636x1041+640-0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, considering 24bit window depth, but switching to Init_BPP32_B8G8R8A8_M1_BIO_TTB(); fixed the problem.